# preg_replace with arrays containing similar keywords

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have two arrays, one containing keywords and one URLs. The code I wrote is linking the keywords to the URLs. It's working fine unless I add keywords containing words that are keywords (I hope it makes sense).

For example, if I add both keyword `happy` and keyword `happy man`, and I have this string: `He is happy, he is a happy man.`, the linking result will be: `He is <b>happy</b>, he is a <b>happy</b> man.`

The result I'm looking for is `He is <b>happy</b>, he is a <b>happy man</b>.` I want preg_replace to replace both `happy` and `happy man` accordingly.

My question is, is there a way to do this?

This is the regex I'm currently using: `/\b keyword \b/i`

Comment: Regex is *okay*... How are you looping over the keywords? My guess is you're breaking out of it early.

Comment: The important thing here is the order in which you do things. The most specific one (in your example `happy man`) should be at the top, so by the time you get as far as `happy` it will already have been replaced.

Comment: I don't believe word boundaries (`\b`) match spaces; so 'happy man' won't be matched. (Edit: I am wrong; `\b` will match the keyword with spaces, as long as `\b` is placed before or after a word character.

Comment: I'm using a while loop to store keywords and URLs form DB in arrays. It's working fine with unique keywords. If I have "happy man" and "happy" is not added as a keyword, "happy man" will be replaced accordingly.